# React Navigation with Redux in RN app

Tags: meteor, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I use Redux in an RN app.
How can I redirect users when they loggedin ?
Where should I put the code: ActionCreator or Reducer ? Sorry very newbie to this
(ps: I know the auth is working with console.log)

here is the action creators

```typescript
export const loginUser = ({email, password}) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('erreur dans le sign in')
        return dispatch ({type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL, payload: email});
      } else {
        console.log('pas d erreur dans le signin')
        return dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: email });
      };
    });
  };
};
```

And the AuthReducer

```typescript
export default (state= INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  //console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:
      console.log('Changed!')
      return {...state, email: action.payload}; // {...state} => so the object is updated

    case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
      console.log('password changed')
      return{...state, password: action.payload};

    case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
      console.log('from login user fail reducer');
      return {...state, email:'fail'};

    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      console.log('from login user success reducer');
      return {...state, email:'success'}

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I handle routing based on the results of an API request etc. in the Action Creator.

The exact method would depend on what router you are using.

```
export const loginUser = ( {email, password, navigator})=>{

    return (dispatch)=>{
          Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log('erreur dans le sign in')
            return dispatch ({type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL, payload: email});
          }else{
            console.log('pas d erreur dans le signin')
            dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: email });

            // Route to new location
            return navigator.replace(Router.getRoute('accounts', { fromLogin: true }))
          };
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: @Sonia Sounds like your real issue is to do with your navigation code itself, rather than just where to initiate the navigation action from.
Does the navigation work when triggered from a different location? Are you passing the `navigate` function through to your action creator?
Perhaps you should amend the question or provide the details of your reactnavigation setup which may allow you to receive a better answer.

Comment: @Sonia If one of the current answers satisfies your question, please can one of them be accepted?

Comment: Rob, the navigation is actually working from a different location. Maybe I should use a navigation reducer ?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to make a redirection will be in your action creator. 
 
Because it will be triggered just the instant the login is successful and the code would be cleaner.

```
export const loginUser = ({email, password}) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('erreur dans le sign in')
        return dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL, payload: email});
      } else {
        console.log('pas d erreur dans le signin')
        // Your code to redirect
        return dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: email});
      };
    });
  };
};
```

In your reducer is not a good idea because it's purpose is just handle de app state.

Another option would be to make the redirect in the component you are requesting the login.

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.email === 'success') {
    // Your code to redirect
  }
}
```